# Using getValues() in Ext.FormPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a problems with getValues() in my ExtJs 3.4 project.
I want to get fields values to send it to server.
I says:

```
alert(searchform.getForm().getValues());
```

And get: `[object Object]`. Okey, i says:

```
alert(searchform.getForm().getValues(true));
```

And get: `cadastr_search=fd&address_search=fgdsg&cadastr_origin_search=gfdg&area_search=gdf&area_origin_search=fdgdf`.

Its possible to get pairs `fieldName: value`?

Comment: I think searchform.getForm().getValues() returns an object. meaning it contains the key : value pair so obj=searchform.getForm().getValues(); obj.cadastr_search should return 'fd'

Comment: Yeah its really works. If you want u can convert your comment to answer and i accept it.

Comment: You asked for Key value pairs? And not how to access a property of a object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
console.log(searchform.getForm().getValues());
```

`alert()` is not capable of printing JavaScript objects.

To get a JSON string call

```
Ext.util.encode(searchform.getForm().getValues())
```

[API ref](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.util.JSON-method-encode)

**Edit**

Like this

```
var obj = searchform.getForm().getValues();
for (var prop in obj) {
    alert(prop + " : " + obj[prop]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah i know that getValues() returns a object. But how to get a values from it?

Comment: @KliverMax Edit done. Quick one! Store the `getValues()` result in a `var` for performance sake